# Toggle on touch and only show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a image and another div.

```
<img src="clock.jpg" id="date"/>
<div id="toggleDIV"> toggleDIV </div>
```

How do I make `#toggleDIV'` show every time the button is clicked but to toggle view when it's touched? So on a touch device I want the button to work as and ON/OFF button but on none touch devices I want it to work only as ON.

```
$("#date").click(function(){
  if ($('#toggleDIV').css('display')=='none')
    $('#toggleDIV').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need for that if condition.

Comment: `<div id="toggleDIV'">` means that the ID of the div is `toggleDIV'` (note the apostrophe at the end, this might be causing problems?

Comment: You can use CSS media queries to determine if the user is browsing via a mobile device. From there you can supply separate CSS rules so that the `#toggleDiv` element is always shown. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @AnoopJoshi thanks. It is important I guess. so the effect doesn't fire if it's already visible.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Also, @AnoopJoshi is correct in that you don't need the `if` condition. jQuery will automatically determine if the element is visible and not run the code again.

Comment: You'll want to check if the browser is mobile somehow, here is a quick mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/hb76b79c/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yes I see that. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @TRGWII Please don't use browser sniffing. It's incredibly outdated and very unreliable. There's a reason jQuery dropped it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$("#date").click(function(){
    $('#toggleDIV:hidden').fadeIn();
});
$("#date").on("touchstart", function(){
    $("#date").off("click");
    $('#toggleDIV').fadeToggle();
});
```

How it works: When you click the button the `div` will always show, but when you touch the button, the `click` event handler will be removed from the button and it will instead run the `touch` handler.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0vfcpLy/)

Note: See @Rory's comment why not to use browser sniffing.